# PHP Map to use key in value for associative array

Tags: php

I have the following given associative array, showing me how many items I have of each key.

```
'story' => 10
'image' => 20
'video' => 30
'audio' => 40
```

I'm trying to transform the array so I can use the key string inside my value, I want to get the following result

```
'story' => 'Story (10)'
'image' => 'Image (20)'
'video' => 'Video (30)'
'audio' => 'Audio (40)'
```

### I've tried

I've tried the following method, but it resets the keys to indexes (0, 1, 2, 3)

```
return array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    return $key . "(" . $value . ")";
}, array_keys($mergedArray), $mergedArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) instead of `array_map()`

```
array_walk($mergedArray, function (&$value, $key) { $value = ucwords($key) . "($value)"; });
print_r($mergedArray);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/533d2)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [story] => Story(10)
    [image] => Image(20)
    [video] => Video(30)
    [audio] => Audio(40)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, is passing by reference supported in PHP7.X? I mean is it something that will keep existing, or be deprecated?

Comment: Yes! it is supported by PHP 7.x. See official [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = [
    "story" => 10,
    "image" => 20,
    "video" => 30,
    "audio" => 40
];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = ucfirst($key)." (".$value.")";
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/8oPVi)